# находиться ли координата GPS внутри МКАД

Tags: gps

Здравствуйте! Раньше особо не работал с координатами GPS. Сейчас возникла задача определить на сервере находиться ли машина с пользователем (пользователь отправляет координаты на сервер) внутри МКАД или он уже его пересек (во внешнем направлении). Наверняка задача типовая и есть какое-то типовое решение. Буду благодарен любым подсказкам. Спасибо!

Comment: Представьте, что МКАД идеально круглый. Узнайте координаты центра Этого круга. Дальше - математика. Будет погрешность, но вы же не ядерные боеголовки запускаете? :)

Comment: Вот вам решение:
[поиск расстояния на машине (параметр driving)](https://gist.github.com/ebritanica/70ffcd401bffb6d209ed5a910e583c1e) Если кто может, то сделайте улучшение кода... хотя думаю что улучшать больше некуда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если можете достать точки полигона МКАД, то можно использовать приложение с [Google Maps Point on Polygon](https://github.com/tparkin/Google-Maps-Point-in-Polygon).
А если нет, то совет Sublihim самое то.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Использовал Ваш совет, точки взял свои (вручную). Точность устроила. Спасибо.